# Difference between these two things?

Tags: vb.net

When people use if statements on booleans, they either do this

```
if booleanStatement = true then
if booleanStatement then
```

I know that they both accomplish the same thing, but is one better than the other? Outside of 'good programming etiquette'

Comment: Just I would recommend writing "true = booleanStatement" so that inadvertantly somebody does not assign value instead of comparison.

Comment: @kanchirk:  That can't happen in VB.Net since the = operator is used for both assignment and equality comparison.

Comment: @Chris Good Point. Thx4TheInfo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `if booleanStatement then` or `if Not booleanStatement then`. 
Why would you wanna write `if true = true then` or `if true = false then`?

Comment: Thanks - I just thought one might've had better performance than the other

Answer (score 4):

In terms of logic of your code, the difference is nil. However, at the risk of starting a war amongst myself and future answer posters, I would say that comes down to naming conventions and code readability.

For example, I would not say that `booleanStatement` is a very descriptive name. If you had something lie this:

```
If result.IsAboveAverage() Then DoSomething()
```

where the `IsAboveAverage()` method of `result` returns a `Boolean` is very readable, and therefore definitely does *not* need `= true`.

For most people who come from C/C++ writing something in the form `booleanExpression == true` is equivalent to crime against humanity. In .NET, however, some of these strict conventions seem to have been relaxed in terms of correct style, because its constituent programming languages were designed for great readability and therefore such things can be allowed for the same reason.

It is really up to you. As long as you pick one way and stick with it, you should not worry about it.

Comment: Can't say I've seen anyone relax about writing `if boolVariable == true` in managed languages either. Can't think of a good reason why they *should*.